# Kill Thread from another process

Tags: python, multithreading

I know that the proper way to kill a Thread subclass is to check periodically if some flag (like `self.running`) is set to a certain "kill" value, but I have a Thread that may hang waiting for input and I'd like to kill it anyway from an external process.

Any help?

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Comment: oh, *another process...* Generally, process cannot get into other process's internals (unless of course it's not a `gdb`). I would either give up (preferred way), or use a debug interfaces.

Comment: That's quite easy to do so long as you don't mind the entire process being killed at the same time.

Comment: The usual way to deal with this problem is to use non-blocking I/O or a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to switch from the threading module to the multiprocessing module for your thread interface, then this is possible. All that needs to be done, is to track the PID of each thread/process that is launched.

```
    from multiprocessing import Process
    import os,time

    class myThread(Process):
        def __init__(self):
            Process.__init__(self)

        def run(self):
            while True:
                os.system("sleep 5")


    if __name__ == '__main__':
         p = myThread()
         p.start()
         print "Main thread PID:",os.getpid()
         print "Launched process PID:",p.pid
         os.kill(p.pid,1)
         p.join()
```